# Error: done() invoked with non-Error: {"code":2,"message":"Unique key violation: ******}

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mocha.js

Alright.. I have been trying to do a unit test with mocha on a create entity function i created to insert files into a AWS S3 bucket. But i keep getting this error

```
Error: done() invoked with non-Error: {"code":2,"message":"Unique key violation: employee#existing@efio.dk"}
```

My code looks like

```
    // Act
    data.saveEntity(type, instance, (err) => {
        console.log("saving existing user");
        if (err) {
            console.log("failed to save user");
            // Assert
            assert.equal(err.code, 2, 'Given inunique key when creating entity then return code 2');
            done();

        }
    })
```

the point of the test is that it should fail if the user exists.
I just can't seem to figure out the problem. Please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you passing done in your it statement?

```
it ('Check this error', function (done) {
 data.saveEntity(type, instance, (err) => {
        console.log("saving existing user");
        if (err) {
            console.log("failed to save user");
            // Assert
            assert.equal(err.code, 2, 'Given inunique key when creating entity then return code 2');
            done();

        }
    })

});
```